# How to copy EC2 snapshots to another amazon account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot

Is there a way to copy an EC2 snapshop made in one amazon account to another one and i.e. lauch a new instance with it? If it's possible, which steps do I have to do exactly? How to allow another account access to your snapshots and how to copy them across? Would appreciate your help.

Comment: I've solved this problem using the cli tools. Following steps have to be done: 1. ec2-modify-snapshot-attribute snapshot-id -c --add second-amazon-account 2. ec2-copy-snapshot -O key -W secret --region target-region --source-region source-region -s snapshot-id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This procedure will help you to share your unencrypted snapshots. For security reasons, encrypted snapshots cannot be shared or made public.

Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.

Click Snapshots in the navigation pane.

The console displays a list of current snapshots and their status.

Select a snapshot and select Modify Snapshot Permissions from the Actions list.

Choose whether to make the snapshot public or to share it with select AWS accounts:

Important
Making your snapshot public shares all snapshot data with everyone. Snapshots with AWS Marketplace product codes cannot be made public.
To make the snapshot public, select Public.

To expose the snapshot only to specific AWS accounts, select Private, enter the ID of the AWS account (without hyphens) in the AWS Account Number field, and click Add Permission. Repeat until you've added all the required AWS accounts.

Click Save when you're done.

**Important**

When you share a snapshot (whether by sharing it with another AWS account or making it public to all), you are giving others access to all the data on your snapshot. Share snapshots only with people with whom you want to share all your snapshot data.

See here for more : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modifying-snapshot-permissions.html

Comment: As of 21 Jun 2016, you can now copy encrypted EBS snapshots across accounts: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-account-copying-of-encrypted-ebs-snapshots/

Answer (score 3):

If you want the other account to launch a clone of one of your instances, you can create an AMI from your instance and add the other account ID to the Permissions on the AMI.

The AMI will then appear in their list of "Shared With Me" AMIs and they can launch it.