# Is there a way to schedule a periodic EBS snapshot transfer between AWS accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to create a EBS snapshot periodically, and transfer it to another AWS account. Is there a way to automate that process?

I know it can be done manually, like described in [How to copy EC2 snapshots to another amazon account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259108/how-to-copy-ec2-snapshots-to-another-amazon-account).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the documentation: [Sharing an Amazon EBS Snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modifying-snapshot-permissions.html)

The steps to translate using aws CLI are

1. Modify permissions on your snapshots

To share privately:

```
    aws ec2 modify-snapshot-attribute \
    --snapshot-id "snap-xxxxx" \
    --create-volume-permission "{
        \"Add\": [
            {
                \"UserId\": \"XXXXXXX\"
            }
        ]
    }"
```

To share publicly:

```
    aws ec2 modify-snapshot-attribute \
    --snapshot-id "snap-xxxxx" \
    --create-volume-permission "{
        \"Add\": [
            {
                \"Group\": \"all\"
            }
        ]
    }"
```

2. Copy the snapshot

   ```
   aws ec2 copy-snapshot \
   --region "target-region"
   --source-region "source" \
   --source-snapshot-id "snap-xxxxx" \
   --description "Example Description"
   ```

be careful not to confuse with `destination-region`

```
   --destination-region (string)
      The  destination  region  to  use in the PresignedUrl parameter of a
      snapshot copy operation. This parameter is only valid for specifying
      the  destination  region  in  a  PresignedUrl parameter, where it is
      required.

      NOTE:
          copy-snapshot sends the snapshot copy to the  regional  endpoint
          that you send the HTTP request to, such as ec2.us-east-1.amazon-
          aws.com (in the AWS CLI, this is  specified  with  the  --region
          parameter or the default region in your AWS configuration file).
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "transferring" a snapshot to a different account, the easiest way is to modify permissions to **permit another account access to the snapshot**.

This way, the snapshot is only stored once rather than paying for double-storage.

Snapshot creation can be [scheduled via Amazon CloudWatch Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/TakeScheduledSnapshot.html). However, this does not allow you to set permissions. Therefore, you will need to either:

- Run a **cron job or Scheduled Task** to run your own code, on your own computer or an an Amazon EC2 instance, or
- Create an **AWS Lambda function** that both creates the snapshot and sets permissions